# Change reason phrase in front of http status code

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, http-status-codes

Hi is there any way to change the standard reason message in front of the HTTP status code, on Spring Boot. For example a response would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Invalid version of request supplied (content-type)
Content-Type: application/json
```

The phrase "Invalid version of request supplied (content-type)" would substitute the standard "Unsupported Media Type".

I have already tried the

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, reason = "Invalid version of request supplied (content-type)")
```

But it doesnt work...

Regards

Comment: Don't. Reason phrases do not exist anymore in HTTP/2.

Comment: Thanx for the input but I really need to do this... Jersey has a way with custom status types but I am having a lot of problems finding a similar approach for Spring Boot.

Comment: It is not going to work with HTTP/2. Why bother?